# Проблема с плагином WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Это код - часть моего плагина, где я с кнопки запускаю его у себя в админ панели. Смысл данной функции - менять описание у товаров, то есть изменить каждую запись товара в бд.

Проблема состоит в том, что мне нужно обработать большой объем данных, а функция попросту не успевает отработать, т.к. выкидывает ошибку 500.

Настройки php.ini и .htaccess не помогли. Есть вариант, как дать ему обработать до конца? Как мне это можно реализовать?

```php
 public function update_product_descriptions()
    {
        $selected_category = $_POST['product_category'];
        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ];

        if ($selected_category != "15") {
            $args['tax_query'] = [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' =>  $selected_category,
                ]
            ];
        }

        $products = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $new_text = "Example";
            wp_update_post([
                'ID' => $product->ID,
                'post_content' => $new_text,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Выполнить данную задачу в фоне, периодически опрашивая сервер с клиента о текущем его статусе.

Comment: https://actionscheduler.org/